# Is there a JNLP Un-install event?

Tags: java, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

Does Java Web Start have any callback when your JNLP deployed app is going to be un-installed (either via Add/remove programs or Java Control Panel)?

Reason for this is to delete any app-generated artifacts & directories.

Comment: +1 for thinking of keeping your user's disk clean of (post use) application baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [ExtensionInstallerService demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis)

> Java web start (JWS) offers the `installer-desc` element to identify an installer/**uninstaller** for an application. The intent of the installer is to do any application set-up/**pull-down** that can not be handled by the standard JWS behaviour of caching the classes/resources at 1st launch, and clearing them at uninstall.

Emphasis mine ( quote from my demo. ;).

Comment: got it deployed using the included ant script
should
 `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Thank you for using (Trivial) Application!");`
execute when you remove the app via Add/remove or Java control panel?

java version = 1.6.0_12-b04

Comment: I've tried uninstall with:

1. win Add/remove
2. java control panel
3. javaws -uninstall application.jnlp

but no JOptionPane.showMsgDialog was executed. at least in my `java version = 1.6.0_12-b04`

Comment: @thirdy: I just tried it on Windows 7, using the normal Windows 'uninstall program' facility in the control panel, and got the final `Thank you for using (Trivial) Application!` option pane.  That was using Oracle's 1.6.0_26-b03 version.  Perhaps you should add your negative result to either of the two (closed) bug reports that are linked from the demo. page.  :(  One of those bug reports uses the demo. code as the test case.

Comment: I was able to try and got it working on a Java 1.6.0_21-b07, Windows XP. Tried again on my workstation (java6 update 12), and confirmed that it does not work. I'll do add a report. Thanks a lot!